# Retry logic in Firebase Queue

Tags: node.js, firebase-queue

I am using fire-base queue in my node.js application. I want to understand, if there is any way available so that a queue can **retry and process remaining tasks** in case error occurred while execution of any task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/blob/master/docs/guide.md#defining-specs-optional), you can specify the number of retry attempts using `retries` (which defaults to zero):

> `retries` - The default spec doesn't retry failed tasks. When a task fails, if there are any remaining attempts, the queue will restart the task by setting the task's `_state` to its spec's `start_state`.